# Using aptitude to install extra php modules (after php has already been installed)?

Tags: php, module, fastcgi, ubuntu-server, aptitude

I recently setup an Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS server for a client which uses a PHP based forum. It's all gone well, but now it seems I need to install a new php module to enable spell checking in the forum (the forum is [Simple Machines Forum](http://www.simplemachines.org/))

So when I first setup the server, I installed like this:

```
sudo aptitude -y install php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql php5-suhosin php5-gd
sudo aptitude -y install php5-fpm php5-cgi php-pear php5-memcache php-apc
```

Now it seems I need 'php5-pspell' as well. But because this server is now live and working, I'm worried that I won't do this right and mess something up...

Can I just do this and then restart the php5-fpm service to make it enabled?

```
sudo aptitude -y install php5-pspell
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much it on Ubuntu: Install the package and restart the webserver. You may have to add it to a new .ini file you create in the /etc/php.d(I believe) directory too. The file's syntax is basically:

```
extension=filename.so
```

You can copy one of the ones that is already there(mysql for example) and just change the filenames.